# multi-dimensional array to HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I'm trying to do a php multi-dimensional array conversion to an HTML table.

The problem is that I would like to organize the table with `rowspan` and `colspan` in order to reflect the array structure. I know it works but I would not like to use a table inside another table.

Below is an example of an array and the expected result.

**Edit:**
Below also my current result (without `rowspan` and `colspan`)
My attempt using rownspan resulted in a complete mess. Rhe table completely lost its structure.

**Edit2:**
Below also my source and the actual result from it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => Array
        (
            [test2_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ID
                    [1] => name
                    [2] => data
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [test3_id] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => ID
                                    [1] => name
                                    [2] => info
                                    [3] => data
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => info
                )

        )

    [2] => name
    [3] => Array
        (
            [test4_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ID
                    [1] => name
                    [2] => info
                    [3] => data
                )

        )

    [4] => data
    [5] => info
)
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMJC0.png)
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Zbs.png)

php:

```
echo '<table border= 1>';
$this->iterate($array, 4);
echo '</table>';

function iterate($array, $level)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($array as $key=>$row)
    {
        if (is_array($row) )
        {
            echo '<th rowspan="1" colspan="'.count($row, COUNT_RECURSIVE).'">';
            echo key($row);
            echo '</th>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<th rowspan="'.$level.'" >'.$row.'</th>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($array  as $key=>$row)
    {
        if (is_array($row) )
        {
            $this->iterate($row, $level -1);
        }
    }   
}
```

One of the problem I encountered was that the COUNT_RECURSIVE command includes the keys along with the values. I would have to do the manual iteration to get the correct count (for the colspan)

Below the image of the result:
[php reult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIlrx.png)

Comment: You've provided the expected result and the array which is good. Have you got the current result / current attempt too?

Comment: I would use ordered lists or unordered lists to achieve this - I don't see how nesting is avoidable without some kind of array flatten function

Comment: Could you show us (code) what you've put together already and where it doesn't work as you expect/want it to?

Comment: @Script47 
I added the image of the current result and a brief explanation

Comment: @jibsteroos
I added the portion of the code responsible for creating the table